# Strategies to prove inequalities with interval notation

Tags: reference-request, inequality

How to prove a inequalities with interval notation, for example:

> Find *minimum* of $a^3+b^3+c^3$ with $a,b,c \in [-1;\infty), a^2+b^2+c^2=9$

Comment: @D3roX4 Have you studied multivariable calculus? Do you know about [Lagrange multiplier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier)?

Comment: Yes, a little. But I still want know *all* the way because in $9th$ grade, Lagrange multiplier is not allowed.

Comment: when $ (a,b,c)=(-1,-1,\sqrt{7})$,then $\min{\{a^3+b^3+c^3\}}=7\sqrt{7}-2$

Comment: @GitGud But $a^2+b^2+c^2=9$

Comment: @math110 $(\sqrt 3, \sqrt 3, \sqrt 3)$ beats that.

Comment: oh.I have some idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly $a, b, c$ cannot be all negative.

If $a, b, c$ are all non-negative, then by Power mean inequality $(\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{3})^2 \geq (\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{3})^3=27$, so $a^3+b^3+c^3 \geq 9\sqrt{3}$ with equality when $a=b=c=\sqrt{3}$.

If exactly 1 of $a, b, c$ is negative, then WLOG assume that $c$ is negative, so $a, b$ are non-negative. Then $c \geq -1$, so $c^2 \leq 1$ so $a^2+b^2 \geq 8$. By Power mean inequality $(\frac{a^3+b^3}{2})^2 \geq (\frac{a^2+b^2}{2})^3 \geq (\frac{8}{2})^3=64$, so $a^3+b^3+c^3 \geq 2\sqrt{64}+c^3 \geq 16-1=15$, with equality when $a=b=2, c=-1$. (and permutations)

If exactly 2 of $a, b, c$ are negative, then WLOG assume that $b, c$ are negative and $a$ is non-negative. We have $b, c \geq -1$, so $b^2, c^2 \leq 1$, so $a^2 \geq 7$, so $a^3+b^3+c^3 \geq (\sqrt{7})^3-1-1=7\sqrt{7}-2$, with equality when $a=\sqrt{7}, b=c=-1$. (and permutations)

Thus $a^3+b^3+c^3 \geq \min(9\sqrt{3}, 15, 7\sqrt{7}-2)=15$, with equality when $a=b=2, c=-1$ and permutations.

Answer (score -2):

By [Holder](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/H%C3%B6lder%27s_Inequality): if $a,b,c>0$
$$(a^3+b^3+c^3)(a^3+b^3+c^3)(1+1+1)\ge (a^2+b^2+c^2)^3$$

then 
$$a^3+b^3+c^3\ge 9\sqrt{3}$$
and when $a=b=c=\sqrt{3}$

case 2:let $a\ge b\ge 0>c\ge -1$
then $a^2+b^2>8$,then $a>2sqrt{2}$,so $a^3+b^3+c^3>a^3+c^3>a^3-1>\sqrt{512}-1>9\sqrt{3}$

case 3:let $a>0>b>c\ge -1$,and we have $a^2>7$,so $a>\sqrt{7}$,then

$a^3+b^3+c^3>\sqrt{343}-2>9\sqrt{3}$

Comment: What is Holder?

Comment: As I remember, Holder is just for nonnegative real numbers.

Comment: @D3r0X4 should be heeded. In this case, you should use absolute values. For e.g. $-1, 2 ,2$ beats this solution!

Comment: Does someone mind providing a link for this Holder thing?

Comment: @Macavity Curiously [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimum+x%5E3%2By%5E3%2Bz%5E3+subject+to+x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3D9+and+x%3E%3D-1%2C+y%3E%3D-1%2C+z%3E%3D-1) can't find your solution.

Comment: @GitGud http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Hölder's_Inequality

Comment: @Macavity Thanks.

Comment: @math110 I took the liberty of adding a link to your answer.

Comment: yes,I have edit,

Comment: In your case 2, $a \ge 2$. So that case doesn't work.